# Is there a way to find out who was logged on a Windows server in a past year?

Tags: windows, user-management

I'm just wondering, is there a way to find out who was logged on a particular Windows server in the past year? Security log is only 1 month old or less and user profiles were deleted. Thanks a lot for any tips.

Comment: Is this a domain joined machine? Did the users log in on other machines since then?

Comment: Hi, yes, it is domain joined. Users were also logged in other machines.

Comment: I was hoping that you could find some information on the users attributes in AD. But I can only see last logon timestamps, not where they were logged on... However perhaps you can dig further and find something there?

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but user profiles are deleted regularly from the server due to disk space.

Comment: Actually, I need to find out this information just to see if the servers are being used, and if not, they will be decommissioned. I think I will just power them off temporarily and see if someone will miss them :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out who was logged on a Windows server in a past year?

Yes, by checking the logs.

> Security log is only 1 month old or less and user profiles were deleted.

Well, you're out of luck.  You can find out who's logged in in the past month, though.

Comment: What about the LastLogon AD attribute the servers have?

Comment: @Reaces There's no AD attribute that tracks which users log on to a particular computer.

Comment: I ment taking into account his comment about simply needing to know if a particular server is being used at all. (regardless of which users log in)

Comment: @Reaces that comment thread's a trainwreck, frankly.  Makes me want to close the question.  If the security logs only go back a month, obviously it's being used ... and there's a log with a month's worth of logins to demonstrate its use. :/

Comment: I know it can be done by checking logs, or timestamp on user profiles. I just wanted to know if there is any other way, but there probably isn't. Thanks anyway for your comments, I will have to work with what I have :)